# Should classes mimick reality or have optimal code compatibility?

Tags: model-view-controller, class-diagram

For a performance monitor I've implemented a MVC in Java and have decided to split up my Model into separate classes, now I'm torn between sorting its attributes and functions into `Client`, `Server` and `Connection` Model classes or `Benchmark`, `Logging` and `Specs` Model classes.

The former Models would match the real life counterparts as "objects", as they are the separate entities the application will monitor.
Due to how the MVC works with an observer, a benchmark function from my controller would trigger updates in all my Models.

The latter would solve this wide-spread updating by making Models match the functionality(requirements) more, thus only updating models that need to be updated, triggering only View-updates that need to be modified.
I think this approach would decrease my Model's re-usability though.

Comment: This would probably be a question for [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @TimF Why that? I've seen modeling questions in tons here on SO. And this is one.

Comment: @ThomasKilian The Programmer's site tour mentions it's for questions on `requirements, architecture, and design`, but maybe both sites are OK with this kind of question.

Comment: @TimF This split is rather strange. I guess that 99% of the questions here on SO deal with "Programming" errors. Interestingly "Programmers" now deals with design and architecture, Not really their top domain I'd expect amongst "Programmers". They should have called it "Analysts/Architects" instead then. Well...

Comment: @ThomasKilian I agree, or even `Managing-programmers`. Anyway concerning UML it's not that clear where it belongs.

Comment: @TimF when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes should touch reality, but not reach it. If you were to stay on an absolute abstract level, your model would not be able to reach some kind of realization. When you model your domain you start with business objects that directly relate to (physical) objects in reality. Once you start designing a system you will **derive** a class model from the business model which is somehow linked. Usually you create dependencies from your system class design to the according business objects and you will also find a naming-parallel. The coupling between business and design model is loosely (dependencies) but existent. Each business object must have some trace to the design model. There will likely be more classes in the design model than in the business model.

Comment: I had directly used my domain(business) model as my class model, but added functions and attributes.
It could make sense that a different categorisation might fit the class diagram better, to structure the program that will eventually run, correct?